# Electric field zero in magnetostatic problem

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, magnetostatics

In a magnetostatic exercise I am given an infinite cylidrical pattern with current density $\vec J$ flowing in the cylinder's axis direction.

My question is, in which cases is the electric field everywhere zero?

Comment: You do see that this is essentially a Homework type question right ? Please try to solve it yourself and show the approach to ask for a specific concept/calculation.

Comment: Hint: Write out the 4 maxwell equations for magnetostatic case, especially the electric field ones. Also invoke the continuity eq. The latter should show that the electric field can never be zero everywhere. Try this out explcitly.

Answer (score 1):

If current is flowing down the length of a cylinder, there must be a source of power and an E field proportional to the current density.